# How to track file combination process in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

When I run a Pig job that loads a large number of small files it pauses for a very long time in this step:

```
2013-07-15 16:44:00,464 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 4277
2013-07-15 16:44:00,465 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 4277
2013-07-15 16:48:51,314 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 37
```

during that period I do not see the map reduce job in the job tracker so I assume Pig is issuing HDFS commands to pre-combine files (maybe?). Once in a while, the job seems to hang there forever for no explainable reason.

Is there any way to monitor the progress of this combination process (see more detail about what it is currently doing)?

Thanks

Comment: Check the namenode logs maybe. That's servicing most of the requests.

Comment: In this period, the client is querying the name node for the metadata of the input files. It is possible to cost a long of time if the file number is large. BTW, how long does it take for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Hadoop Archive](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/hadoop-archive-file-compaction-hdfs-461.html)? This might help bring down the time spent in fetching multiple small files.